# Store pandas data in string in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

In for loop I want store my output in string object.

For that i tried the following, But i didn't get a solution.

here out is some user_defined function.

```
for i in range(1,2):
    'out_put%s'%i+'_ests'=out(data)
```

i can do the same thing in R by using the following code.

```
for(i in c(1,2))
 {
   assign(paste0('out_put',i,'_ests'),out(data))
 }
```

Please anyone help me to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string are not variable. You cant store datas in a string.

Comment: Is this really pandas?

Comment: Maybe using `globals`: `globals()['out_put%s'%i+'_ests']=out(data)`

Comment: yes,it's working